# Change the "name" value of a signed Java applet

Tags: java, applet, signing

I've self-signed a java applet, so when a user views this applet in a browser, the browser will show a *digital signature cannot be verified* confirmation dialog. That's all ok, however the value of the "Name:" property (seen above the "Publisher:" property) of this confirmation dialog is set to something I don't remember setting when doing the signing.

So my question is, where is this value coming from, and how do I change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found it, it is the name of the applet in the HTML source

Answer (score 2):

If using the <object> tag, add a name parameter:

`<param name="name" value="Name of Applet">`

Comment: Specifying additional name parameter works for <applet> as well. It even overrides the value of the name attribute of <applet name="...">.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above responses, use **Application-Name** property in the MANIFEST.MF inside your (signed) jar.